# Agrupar por mes y por día MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Tengo esta coleccion en Mongo DB:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60bf693232bc91277fc60d0f"),
    "user": ObjectId("60b909c29b6d9664714c028a"),
    "operationName": "package one",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-04-08T12:57:22.685Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-04-08T12:57:22.685Z"),
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60bf693332bc91277fc60d14"),
    "user": ObjectId("60b909c29b6d9664714c028a"),
    "operationName": "package two",
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-06-08T12:57:23.188Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-06-08T12:57:23.188Z"),
  }
]
```

Tengo que realizar una query que me permita filtrar operaciones de un usuario, y agruparlas por el dia de hoy y por los últimos 30 días. A su vez necesito devolver el total de cada operacion por ese mismo criterio.

Hasta ahora solo logré que me devuelva la cantidad de operaciones de los últimos 30 días. Me faltaría que devuelva la cantidad de operaciones del día actual. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "user": {
        "$eq": ObjectId("60b909c29b6d9664714c028a")
      },
      "updatedAt": {
        $gte: ISODate("2021-07-05T0:00:00.00Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2021-08-04T0:00:00.00Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$operationName",
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Lo que me devuelve son el total de cada operacion de los ultimos 30 dias:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "package one",
    "total": 5
  },
  {
    "_id": "package two",
    "total": 2
  }
]
```

Y lo que necesito sería algo así:

```
[
{
  "hoy": {"package one": 2, "package two": 1},
  "mes": {"package one": 5, "package two": 2}
}
]
```

Dejo el link del [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bvccxI01G_z)

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de `$facet` para crear dos caminos difrentes de ejecución, uno para `mes` y otro para `hoy`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "user": ObjectId("60b909c29b6d9664714c028a")
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "mes": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "updatedAt": {
              "$gte": ISODate("2021-06-01T0:00:00.00Z"),
              "$lt": ISODate("2021-07-01T0:00:00.00Z")
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$operationName",
            "total": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "hoy": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "updatedAt": {
              "$gte": ISODate("2021-06-08T0:00:00.00Z"),
              "$lt": ISODate("2021-06-09T0:00:00.00Z")
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$operationName",
            "total": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nmGpRhtnXlj)